# Flutter Firebase get stream of list of document snapshots from list of document references

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

So every user in my collection has a list of references to groupchats that they are a part of
[firestore screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8gDd.png)

I'm trying to get this list and from that create a stream of all those individual Document Snapshot streams. I kinda want something like a collection stream but I don't want to create an actual new collection in my firestore. Then from this list of document snapshots I want to create a widget to represent each groupchat document. In this code below this widget is represented by a Text() Widget but later it will be more fleshed out.

```
Stream getChatsFromRefs(List<DocumentReference> refs) {
    List<Stream<DocumentSnapshot>> chatSnapList =
        List<Stream<DocumentSnapshot>>();
    for (DocumentReference ref in refs) {
      chatSnapList.add(ref.snapshots());
    }

    return Rx.combineLatest(chatSnapList, (values) => values.last);
  }


class ChatList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChatListState createState() => _ChatListState();
}

class _ChatListState extends State<ChatList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DocumentSnapshot userSnapshotData = Provider.of<DocumentSnapshot>(context);
    print("no error so far");
    return StreamBuilder<List<DocumentSnapshot>>(
        stream:
            DatabaseService().getChatsFromRefs(userSnapshotData.data()["refs"]),
        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          final documents = snapshot.data;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, index) => Text(documents[index]["name"]),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

This is what I've most recently tried, but I was left with this error

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrd1J.png)

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you tried to debug your code? it seems like `userSnapshotData.data()["refs"]` returns null

Comment: @mfkw1 Oops yeah you were right about that "refs" isn't the correct field it was supposed to be "chatRefs". I'll let you know if I figure it out from here.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested I figured out the solution.

```
Stream getChatsFromRefs(List<DocumentReference> refs) {
    List<Stream<Chat>> chatStreamList = List<Stream<Chat>>();

    for (DocumentReference ref in refs) {
      chatStreamList.add(ref.snapshots().map(_chatFromDocSnapshot));
    }

    return Rx.combineLatestList(chatStreamList);
  }
```

This approach is superior to using a StreamZip because it will rebuild when any document detects a change which is what I wanted for my purposes.